# How to link text to in adobe indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there a way to link text to a "master text frame"?

Basically, if I have a report, with a title on multiple parts of the page, is there a way to create one text box with the title, and then in subsequent text boxes have them link (use the same text) as the first text box? That way, if I change the title, it automatically changes it throughout the document.

One thought I had was to use data merge, but I was hoping there is an easier solution.

Comment: Have you tried putting it on the master page?

Comment: That was a thought I had, but my hesitation is if I change the format and the text boxes move. That was why I was thinking Data Merge. I was hoping there was a solution similar to linking cells in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this using the Content collector.

Select the frame with your source text in it (Parent)
Select the Content Collector tool, which opens the Content collector Panel- the left most icon - the Collector- picks up the frame you click on (the Parent)
before you place it with the Placer tool (from this Panel), check the  Create Link Button and place it.

The text link now shows in the Links panel 2x, as the Parent and child. The child frame shows a Link badge.
You can duplicate the child  - and any changes made to the parent will update through all the "children" when you update the mods in Links Panel.

Text edits that you make to the parent will update through the children when you update the links in the Panel. I don't think it supports different styles of text.. but there are options that you can set the warnings about updating and overriding.